# Multiple Collapse Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, accordion, bootstrap-5

how do I close all the multicollapses when i open a new one?
Specifically I want the "Accordion Item # 2.1" collapse when I click on "Accordion Item # 1 or" Accordion Item # 3.
My code only closes "Accordion Item # 2" but not the accordion nested in it.

```html
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">  
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> 
        <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="hThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#cThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="cThree">
        Accordion Item #2.1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="cThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="hThree">
      <div class="accordion-body">
      CIAO
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Accept the answer so others know the question is solved

Answer (score 1):

The only way to handle this is using Javascript. First, select all `.collapse` elements and then hook-up the `hidden.bs.collapse` event. As each accordion is hidden, look inside it for open child `.collapse.show` elements. For each open child, obtain the Bootstrap Collapse instance and use the `hide()` method.

```
var collapseElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.collapse'))
var collapseList = collapseElementList.map(function (collapseEl) {
    collapseEl.addEventListener('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        let children = this.querySelectorAll('.collapse.show');
        children.forEach((c)=>{
            var collapse = bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(c)
            collapse.hide()
        })
    })
})
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/zGN9Vrf3Y3